# How to flatten a dict type column in a DF

Tags: julia

i have a df with a dict type column named `measures` like below:

[image]

How can I flatten this column as new columns in the same DF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same problem, wanting to extract and flatten data from a JSON, it might be overkill for your issue and a bit obscure but here it is:

This expects `Dict`s and ignores missing or malformed data

```
function extract_flatten(data::AbstractDict, extract::AbstractDict; cmdchar::AbstractChar='%')
    res = Dict()
    for (key, val) in extract
        temp = Any[data]
        keys = [key]
        for v in val
            if v isa AbstractString
                if v[1] == cmdchar
                    v = split(v[2:end], ':')
                    if v[1] == "all"
                        temp2 = []
                        keys2 = String[]
                        for (t,k) in zip(temp, keys)
                            for (kt,vt) in pairs(t)
                                push!(keys2, join([k; v[2:end]; kt], '_'))
                                push!(temp2, vt)
                            end
                        end
                        temp = temp2
                        keys = keys2
                    elseif v[1] == "name"
                        keys .*= '_' * join(v[2:end], '_')
                    else
                        error("$(repr(v)) is not a valid command")
                    end
                else
                    temp .= getdefnothing.(temp, Ref(v))
                end
            elseif v isa Integer
                temp .= getdefnothing.(temp, Ref(v))
            else
                error("$(repr(v)) is not a valid key")
            end
            nothings = isnothing.(temp)
            deleteat!(temp, nothings)
            deleteat!(keys, nothings)
            isempty(temp) && break
        end
        push!.(Ref(res), keys .=> temp)
    end
    return res
end

getdefnothing(x, y) = nothing
getdefnothing(x::AbstractDict, y) = get(x, y, nothing)
getdefnothing(x::AbstractArray, y) = get(x, y, nothing)
```

example use:

```
using Test
const d = Dict

schema = d(
    "a" => ["b", "c", "d"],
    "b" => ["e"],
    "c" => ["f", "%all:z", "g"]
)

a = d("z" => 3)
@test extract_flatten(a, schema) == d()

b = d("e" => 0.123)
@test extract_flatten(b, schema) == d("b" => 0.123)

c = d("e" => true, "b" => d("c" => d("d" => "ABC")))
@test extract_flatten(c, schema) == d("b" => true, "a" => "ABC")

e = d("f" => d(
    "a" => d("g" => "A"),
    "b" => d("g" => "B")
))
@test extract_flatten(e, schema) == d("c_z_a" => "A", "c_z_b" => "B")

f = d("f" => [
    d("g" => "A"),
    d("g" => "B")
])
@test extract_flatten(f, schema) == d("c_z_1" => "A", "c_z_2" => "B")

g = d("e" => nothing, "f" => [1,2,3])
@test extract_flatten(g, schema) == d()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is only one object in each of those lists, then something like this:

```
using JSON
using dataframes
transform(
    df, 
    (
        :measures => 
        ByRow(d -> (; JSON.parse(d; dicttype=Dict{Symbol,Any})[1]...)) =>
        AsTable
    )
)
```

What this does is parse the entries in the `measures` column as JSON (length-one) lists of dicts, take the first element, convert to a `NamedTuple`, and then use `=> AsTable` to tell `transform` to convert that `NamedTuple` into corresponding columns.

Comment: Right, and if the internal contents is Python then `using PyCall; select(df, :src => ByRow(x -> only(py"$$x")) => AsTable)`.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Good point, the single quotes make it clear it's not actually JSON.

Comment: Thanks for time invested to help me but it gives me an error: Invalid object key Line:0 "  I think its because of the single quotes.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Thans for your help.  It also falis because Collection has multiple elements. Its a prtty deep nested dict like list..

Comment: If it is a deep nested dict then there is no generic solution to your problem. You need to manually unnest what you need from the dict.